# Extensible.log is undefined

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extensible

I am trying to get the Calendar Pro from Extensible to work.

if I do everything as the [example says here](http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/calendar/basic.html), I get an undefined for the **log** function on **Extensible.js** :

[image]

However everything looks alright in my code :

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false,
    paths: {
        "Extensible": "js/lib/extensible-1.5.2/src",
        "Extensible.example": "js/lib/extensible-1.5.2/examples"
    }
});
Ext.require([

    'Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel',
    'Extensible.calendar.data.MemoryEventStore',
    'Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel',
    'Extensible.example.calendar.data.Events'
]);
```

Both the **src** and the **examples** paths are correct.

My Extinsible folder structure sits next to the extjs src like this :

[image]

It seems like I am missing something or Extensible is not yet being initialised properly.

Comment: How are you getting the main Extensible js file in your app? Don't you have to require 'Extensible.Extensible' or are one of those calendar requires pulling it in?

Comment: you mean put 'Extensible.Extensible' in requires?

Comment: ok works now :) @pherris you can add ur comment as an answer and i can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just forgot to include the Extensible.js by adding it to your requires statement:

```
Ext.require([
    'Extensible.Extensible', //here
    'Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel',
    'Extensible.calendar.data.MemoryEventStore',
    'Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel',
    'Extensible.example.calendar.data.Events'
]);
```

This will include the main Extinsible.js file as well as the calendar and example files.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on the [support forums](http://ext.ensible.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=786&p=3155&hilit=extensible.log#p3155):

> The Extensible.log error typically means that you are using the source
>   code from Github without compiling it first. Either run the build
>   script per the README file, or stick to the download zip containing
>   the pre-built files.

If you are using a properly-built version of the framework and still getting this error then you might provide more details about how you set things up.

Comment: I think pherris has the right answer. I just need to import Extensible. In your demo you don't have that import, so not sure why it works in your demo. Anyways..

Comment: The demos work because they are using the built version of the library, not the source downloaded from Github. Once you build properly you won't need to include `Extensible.Extensible` -- that's a hack based on how you set things up. But if it works for you, go for it.